# Bootstrap - Occupy all space of the table

Tags: javascript, calendar

I'm new to Bootstrap 4 and I'm creating a calendar using tables. I want to occupy the entire space of the body, I don't know how to adjust its height with responsive.

[image]

Comment: add your HTML Java script and ccs

Comment: Thy this.

https://codepen.io/chrisdpratt/pen/OOybam/